# Trying to bring a username name from login at my home page

Tags: javascript, html

```
loginForm.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault() 

    var emailLoginInput = loginForm.querySelector('#email')
    var passwordLoginInput = loginForm.querySelector('#password')

    var emailLogin = emailLoginInput.value 
    var passwordLogin = passwordLoginInput.value

    emailLoginInput.value = ''
    passwordLoginInput.value = ''

    var checkEmailAndPassword = users.some(u => u.email === emailLogin && u.password === passwordLogin)

    if (checkEmailAndPassword) {
        
        registerView.style.display = 'none'
        loginView.style.display = 'none'
        homeView.style.display = 'block'

        var userLog = {
            username: users.find(user => user.email === emailLogin && user.password === passwordLogin).username
        }

        userLogin.push(userLog)
    } else { 

        document.getElementById('login').querySelector('p').innerText = 'Error: Email or password wrong. Try again'
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    document.getElementById('login').querySelector('p').innerText = 'Introduce your email and password:';
});
```

When I logged in with user credentials (email and password only) with success, I would like to go to my home page and say "Welcome {username}" with the username that I just logged in.

What would it take for the "Welcome" (on page/div = home) to appear followed by the `username[0].username` (the logged-in user)? Any code from JS to write on the index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Is that right？ document.getElementById("xxx") = `Welcome ${username[0].username}!`

[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).